# Reading comport with QT through winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get a list of comports that are currently in use to present them in my GUI.
I'm using the following code:

```
   TCHAR szComPort[8];
   HANDLE hCom = NULL;
   char str[20];

   for (int i = 1; i <= 255; ++i)
   {
       if (i < 10)
         wsprintf(szComPort, ("COM%d"), i);
       else
         wsprintf(szComPort, ("\\\\.\\COM%d"), i);

       hCom = CreateFile(szComPort,
           GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
           0,                          
           NULL,                       
           OPEN_EXISTING,             
           0,                          
           NULL);                      

       if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hCom)
       {
           sprintf_s(str,"COM%d",i);
           ui->COMLIST->addItem(str);
       }
       CloseHandle(hCom);
   }
```

This works fine on my laptop but for some reason it crashes QT on my PC for comports 10 and higher (meaning if i change i<=255 to i<=9 it works fine),

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 8 wchars in the `szComPort` buffer, you you are writing 10 characters for COM10 and above and 11 characters for COM11 and above. Make the buffer at least 11 units.

Edit: The usual practice is to make the buffer simply large enough with enough slop so you don't have to count characters. I'd probably just look at the string, think it has about 10 characters so with something for the formatted value it won't result in 30 and declare the buffer 32 items. The stack has enough room for this few extra bytes and you are not even initializing it, so there is no performance penalty and it's less risk.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't it 7, I mean each \\ is actually a \ in the string (it does work though...)

Comment: %d expands to two characters for i >= 10, and three characters for i >= 100. Use a debugger and see for yourself if you are unsure.

Comment: @HelloWorld: I know how to count a `'\\'`. But it's 11: 2 \, 1 `.`,  1 \, 3 letters `COM` (that makes 7 character prefix), than 3 digits from %d (your highest number is 255) and very importantly **terminating 0**. That's 11 characters.

Comment: Yes, I did see you are both right using the debugger. Was just wandering. Thank you both! And sorry for the dumb question.